# Why is this C linked list corrupting? 

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list

I have not taken a CS class in 2 years I can not figure out why this simple linked list is corrupting:

```
int exists(linkedlist *list, int val) {
    if(list == NULL)
        return 0;

    if(list->value == val)
        return 1;
    return exists(list->next, val);
}
```

When I try to execute `exists(list,33);` the first value of the list is overwritten with 33.  I was forced to use an iterative approach and got the program working, however this bugs me since this appears to be a valid solution.  Why doesn't it work?

(NOTE: When creating nodes I always set `list->next = NULL;`)

Comment: Are you sure your code says `lists->value == val` not `lists->value = val`?

Comment: Totally unrelated note: the list argument should be const.

Comment: @unwind: Not totally unrelated, I suspect. :)

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure the second if statement is

```
if(list->value == val)
```

and not

```
if(list->value = val)
```

That's the only thing I can see that would change the value.

Comment: A good reason to use `const` when you don't intend to modify a parameter!

Comment: But he's not modifying the parameter.  I don't think `const` would help in this case.

Comment: @TMN: if he has made the mistake that @B Mitch suggests here then he is indeed modifying the parameter. If the parameter was const (i.e. `int exists(const linkedlist *list, int val)`) then that mistake could never happen because the compiler would complain.

Comment: [This example code shows exactly the same situation that the OP describes](http://ideone.com/F6CeI). Adding a `const` to the parameter prevents it from compiling with the handy message `error: assignment of read-only location ‘*list’`

Comment: Disturbingly, it doesn't prevent you from changing the value of `list`, which is what I expected (since that's the actual parameter).

Comment: @TMN: yep that is correct. `const linkedlist *list` says that `list` is a pointer to a `const linkedlist`. You can alter what the pointer points to in the function, but not the thing it points to.  If you want to prevent the pointer from being changed as well for some reason, then the parameter should be declared as `const linkedlist * const list`, which reads as `list` is  `const pointer` to a `const linkedlist`.

Answer (score 1):

What doesn't work exactly? The code looks perfectly OK.

Try running you program in `valgrind`, to check for memory errors you might be missing.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, how long is your linked list?

Probably not your problem here, but be aware that your recursive approach means you could end up with a stack overflow on very long lists.

Comment: Only a few elements.  Maybe it's the way dev-cpp compiles?  I'm getting a corruption of the list.

Where the list used to print as 1, 2, 3.  It would print as 22, 2, 3 after running the above function checking for val=22

Comment: Yes I think the answers from @B Mitch and @nmichaels identify the correct source of problem. The recursion thing is just something else you should probably consider.